# Limit minutes list on datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails on a web application.
I would like to know if its possible to tell `datetime_select` to only have two options in the minutes drop down list? Options 00 and 30.

I have the below code:

```
<p><label for="command_date_to_execute">Date to Run</label><br/>
<%= datetime_select 'command', 'date_to_run', :discard_minute => true  %>:
<%= select 'command', 'date_to_run', ['00', '30'] %>
</p>
```

The browser source produces:

```
<select id="command_date_to_run" name="command[date_to_run]">
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

But I really need is below (with the 5i in the generated HTML):

```
     

<select id="command_date_to_execute_5i" name="command[date_to_execute(5i)]">
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want values 00 and 30 to be displayed for the minutes, you can do the below:

```
= f.datetime_select(:leave_end, :start_year => 2011, :ampm => true, :default => 0.days.from_now.in_time_zone(@timezone), :discard_minute => true) %span : 
= f.select('req_sess_start(5i)', ['00', '30'])
```

This might get exceptions on the page validation due to the (possibly) unknown variable req_sess_start(5i). Will work if validation is met.

The below would work better though as will not throw the exception.

```
= f.datetime_select(:req_sess_start, :start_year => 2011, :ampm => true, :default => 0.days.from_now.in_time_zone(@timezone), :minute_step => 30)
```

Comment: :minute_step is the way to go.  Thanks!